# How far can I resize a x264 video without blurriness?

Tags: video, resolution, x264

I have an x264 video at 700x400 encoded at 1400 Kbps with High Profile Level 3 which I want to play at 1366 x 768 screen resolution. How far can I change or resize the video player window without noticing an quality degrade in picture? I suppose the bit-rate should tell me but I am not sure. The quality is far more better than DiVX video which gets blurry too soon upon resize.

Comment: Only you can decided what is "blurred".

Answer (score 0):

Use a better upscaling algorithm, e.g. bicubic / lanczos / spline instead or bilinear. You don't even need to re-encode the video for that (neither should you, coz re-encoding always cost you quality), just get a player that is can provide you with those (either out-of-the-box or through some filter/renderer), the upscaling can be done "on-the-fly" during the playback.